# How to bind dropdownlist in partial view in mvc 4 using model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi i am using partial view in index.cshtml page. and partial view contains one dropdownlist which is bind dynamically from database.

I don't want to use viewbag or viewdata for binding this dropdownlist.

In Controller

```
    // GET: Reporting/Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var view = View();

        return view;
    }

    public ActionResult _ReportingMenu()
    {
        var DashboardList = GetAllDashboards();

        return View(DashboardList);
    }


    public IEnumerable<DashboardDefinition> GetAllDashboards()
    {
        return _reortDefinitionService.GetAllDashboards();
    }
```

In index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Portal.Domain.ReportingModule.ReportDefinition.DashboardDefinition>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reporting";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Reporting View</h2>
@Html.ActionLink("Add new Chart", "Create", "Chart", new { area = "Reporting" }, null)

@Html.Partial("_ReportingMenu")
```

In Partialview

```
    @model  Portal.Domain.ReportingModule.ReportDefinition.DashboardDefinition

    <div class="nav navbar navbar-default navbar-no-margin submenu">

        @Html.DropDownList("Mobiledropdown1",IEnumerable<Model.DashboardName>)   

        <a id="SubMenuIntegratorNew" class="btn btn-default submenu-item" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-lg"></i>
            <span class="submenu-item-text">New</span>
        </a>
        <a id="SubMenuIntegratorSave" class="btn btn-default submenu-item" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-lg"></i>
            <span class="submenu-item-text">Save</span>
        </a>
        <a id="SubMenuIntegratorSaveAs" class="btn btn-default submenu-item" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-files-o  fa-lg"></i>
            <span class="submenu-item-text">Save As</span>
        </a>
        <a id="SubMenuIntegratorAddChart" class="btn btn-default submenu-item" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-lg"></i>
            <span class="submenu-item-text">Add Chart</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

but i get an error of null model.

I don't know how to implement in partial view

Comment: The second parameter of `DropDownListFor()` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (either that or you need a `ViewBag` property named `Mobiledropdown1` which is  `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) What is your model (do you really have a property named `Mobiledropdown1`) And why are your not using the strongly typed helper? And show the full details of the exception.

Comment: There is @Html.Partial(string viewName, object model) so you can pass model to strongly typed partial view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a view model, so you can contain both the list and the selected property in it, something like:

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Data { get; set; }
    //Might not be an int, but just an example
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
}
```

Then populate it in your controller:

```
public ActionResult _ReportingMenu()
{
    var DashboardList = GetAllDashboards();

    var dropdownData = DashboardList
        .Select(d => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = d.Name, //Need to apply the correct text field here
            Value = d.Id.ToString() //Need to apply the correct value field here
        })
        .ToList();

    var model = new DashboardViewModel
    {
       Data = dropdownData 
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your both your views, set the model:

```
 @model DashboardViewModel
```

Then in your partial you can do:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, Model.Data)
```

Comment: Property `Data` would need to be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` or `SelectList`, or the helper would need to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, new SelectList(Model.Data, "valueField", "textField"))`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Good shout I neglected that, updated to reflect.

Comment: i have done using     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, new SelectList(Model.Data, "valueField", "textField")) 

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @KaranPatel Yeah that's fine also.

Answer (score 0):

defining Model:

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Data { get; set; }
public int SelectedId { get; set; }
}
```

in your view set:

```
@Html.Partial("YourActionName", (SelectList)ViewBag.yourViewBagName)
```

in your top of partialview, set the model:

```
@model DashboardViewModel
```

in your Partialview set:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id", new SelectList(Model.Items, "Id", "Name"), new {@class = "form-control", })
```